# Can not connect to my ms-sql server through nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I recently transferred a project to my desktop over from my laptop, and am trying to get the sql server set up.  I'm testing out the server to make sure it works, and have set up a test table in my sql database.  Whenever I try to input data into the table I get the following error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Connection is closed.

I'm able to log into the server using the credentials outlined in the code below through SSMS.  Here is the code I am using:

```
const express = require('express');
var sql = require('mssql');
const app = express();

var config = {
    user: 'djaenike',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'JAENIKE_DESKTOP', 
    database: 'master'
};

app.post('/testing', (req, res) => {
  console.log('request made')
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    let connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config, function(err) {
      let request = new sql.Request(connection);
      request.query("insert into testTable (test) values ('a test')");
    })
    res.send(req.query);
    sql.close();
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000; //get the process port
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

I'm using postman to make a request to http://localhost:5000/testing and am getting the "request made" in my console window, just can't seem to establish a connection.  Any advice on how to troubleshoot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - had to enable TCP/IP protocol in the network configurator.  All set